# Someone knows if there is a git repo similar to evernote stack view for android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, view

I'm making an app for android and iOS and i was looking if someone can point me to a git repo or a sample code for simulating the stack view inside the Evernote app for iOS. I found a git repo to help me make this posible for iOS ( to see of what i'm talking about here is the git: [iOS evernote like view](https://github.com/KieranLafferty/KLNoteViewController) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/ I think it is very close to iOS evernote component.

Comment: oh ... i know about androidviews site, but i don't know how did i miss cardsui ... i think i can work with that. Will mark as accepted for now.